# How to change character limit in split sms javascript?

Tags: javascript, split, sms

I am using [split-sms](https://github.com/Codesleuth/split-sms)
it splits segment by 2 when character is over 160 and unicode character is over 70. But I want to change this behavior.
I want to do 153 character limits and 67 characters limit in unicode.
Can anyone give me a hint where to change?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like uou need to modify the code provided by split-sms.js
in

```
module.exports.split = function (message, options) {
...
if (isGsm) {
    splitResult = gsmSplitter.split(message, options);
    singleBytes = 153;
    multiBytes = 146;
    charBytes = 1;
  } else {
    splitResult = unicodeSplitter.split(message, options);
    singleBytes = 134;
    multiBytes = 128;
    charBytes = 2;
  }
....
}
```

Comment: I changed the code like you said, but calculateRemaining function doesn't work properly.

Comment: I just realised there are couple of more places you need to change 160 to 153